# Could not find or load main class Mac terminal .java

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I am using Mac Big Sur terminal.

I have a .java file. I can compile using:
javac DeptQuery.java

where it creates the class file within the same directory. But then when I type

java DeptQuery

to run it, it give the error: "Error: Could not find or load main class DeptQuery"

I also can't open the .java file from the terminal, I can only compile it from there.

Comment: Is there a package declaration in the java file?

Comment: Use the command `vi DeptQuery.java` and check if you have a package declaration at the top.